# How can I add my one entity with uppercase?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want the city entity to be all uppercase. Are there any easy way to do it?

```java
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String city;

    private String district;
```

Implementation

```java
@Override
public boolean addAddress(Address address) {
    Address save = (Address) addressRepository.save(address);

    if (save == null)
        return false;
    return true;
```

Comment: You can try adding a getter method for the city which formats the String to a desired format although I wouldn't recommend this approach. The "addAddress" function should already receive a formatted object. Therefore, you should format the Address object before passing it to the "addAddress" function

Comment: in your `addAddress` method, you can do something like  `address.setCity(address.getCity().toUpperCase());` before calling `save` method of `addressRepository`

Answer (score 1):

What I understood is that you want to save the city in capital letters in the database, if so, do the following:

in service class add function CityUpperCase()

```
public Address CityUpperCase(Address address){
address.setCity(getCity().toUpperCase() );
return address;
}
```

And modify the code on the Service in the addAddress function as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean addAddress(Address address) {

Address save = (Address) addressRepository.save(CityUpperCase(address));

if (save == null){

      return false;

   }else{

      return true;

   }
}
```